# Talked to Omega but can't find the Director Mode option?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I talked to Omega (stranger and freak mission) and I don't see the director mode option. Where is it? I'm playing on Xbox One.

Answer (score 1):

The director mode can be found in the pause menu by navigating to Rockstar Editor[image: Pause Menu Director Mode]

Please note that Director mode may be unavailable if

> the player is currently in a vehicle, wanted or active in a mission.

Source: [GTA Wiki](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Director_Mode)